# How can I make my View stay up to date with the changing data inside of my Controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug

I have one view and one controller so far... (I simplified my controller to be more clear in what I'm asking)

View.jade:

```
div
    p List size:
        span(ng-bind="list.length")
    button(ng-click="") Button
```

MyCtrl.js:

```
angular.module('MyModule')
  .controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.list = [];

    < list is constanting being added to here (I'm sure of it!) >

  });
```

**My problem:**

The shown value for list.length is only updating when I click my pointless button and I can't figure out why.

Anything which would keep my shown value for the list's length would be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found it!

After I push to my list I needed to do-

```
$scope.$apply();
```